# Azure Logic Apps, how to track steps? Diagnostic settings?

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-logic-apps

So you can view past runs of Logic Apps(LA)...but if a Loop(with many steps within it) is present in your Logic App, and you stop the LA run(because it seems to run forever/isnt doing what you expect) you cant see what happened in the the Loop.

I want to be able to track the Logic App(LA) progress, i thought about adding an additional table storage step between every step to log where its at, this would work, but thats a daft amount of work just see what your LA is doing.

I tried adding diagnostic/log analytics to the LA but it just seems to give a broader view of the LA runs...not the detail i need. Can someone tell me if diagnositcs can give me the detail im looking for OR if there is another way of doing this. There must be a way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The past runs should allow you iterate though the runs of the loop, showing the detail of actions within.

[image]

If this doesn't satisfy, you can also add [Tracked Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#azure-monitor-diagnostics-events) to log specific values from within the loop execution to Log Analytics in an AzureDiagnostics table

[image]

[image]

Comment: when the loop fails....or you stop it early, you cant open the loop (instead of a green tick....it will show a grey cross), so you cant step into the loop to look at values(even though i know it has looped many times)...I did see the tracked properties, so i can maybe try this within a failing loop and see if they do get written out.     I still think you can view the logging in a table(or whatever) somewhere....we know the steps are logged as that is what allows you to look at past runs, but there has to be an easier way of viewing this than clicking through logic apps?